How to restrict Feature Service access to only one particular user
We have a single user license for our ArcGIS Portal with different feature and map services. Different clients access each of these services.
Is it possible to set up each feature service with it own username, password and tokens; without other client using or consuming the others data?
To explain more; our Login credentials to portal -- is "AAAA" -- a single user with a license.
We want to create a new user, "BBBB". Only this user will have access to the feature service.
Our ArcGIS Portal is federated with an ArcGIS Server.

There are a few ways you could go about this.
After creating a 2nd user account, you could simply re-assign the feature service to the new user, making sure that the feature service item is NOT shared to anyone in the Portal. (Portal users only have access to their own content by default, unless the item is shared to either the Org or Publicly).
Alternatively, you can make use of groups. Create groups, assign users to those groups, and then share content to said group.
Start here to dig into this concept.
The 1st method is more straight forward, but you're delegating the entire service to someone else and this would also require the user to have a publisher license. The 2nd option is a little more work, but I believe would be the correct approach for most situations; especially if your user only has a viewer license.

Sorry, cant afford to have 2nd user account.! in the 2nd method, is it still possible to create user group with single user license,. Sorry, I am new to ArcGIS Server; havent had enough workaround to get this done!

I'm confused - you say you want to create a new user, but your license restricts you to just a single user in your Portal? If you can't create more users, you can't restrict access to various users. There's no workaround to this. Its like saying you want everyone to have their own email account, but you're restricted to only opening a single account.

Got you!,. is there any other way to authenticate only particular service with token or using OAuth tool?

I'd check with your Esri account manager about getting more user accounts. I'm no license expert, but I thought everyone had access to viewer accounts.

Viewer is around $220 per user (depending on region) source https://www.sigsa.info/es-mx/arcgis/products/user-types/buy

That price is for ArcGIS Online. My comment was specific to Enterprise. And you may not need to involve the account manager. You might be able to self-serve viewer licenses out of MyEsri.



Got you!,. is there any other way to authenticate only particular service with token or using OAuth tool? –  Nannan Satish


Yes, there are a few ways you can do this but would require the credentials to do so. Without knowing the details of your architecture or your resources I can't give you a complete solution but, it can be done this way.
Create an application (web or desktop) that connects to your REST API and can perform the work that you need to do or render a map. The rub is that you would have to include the credentials in the code for the login or setup another source to authenticate e.g. Webservice connected to SQL that can pass the login information securely.
All this being said, it would definitely be cheaper to add a viewer account or if edits needed to be made a creator or whatever they call them now.
